# Remove all rows Except condition

Tags: sql, database, where-clause

I would like to remove all rows from the table **EXCEPT** when `FirstName` is **Ben** and `isAdmin` is true

Here is my SQL

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE (FirstName <> 'Ben' AND isAdmin = 1);
```

However, my issue is that when `isAdmin` is false... it should remove that row as well but it doesn't remove it. What is my issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct SQL should be

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE (FirstName <> 'Ben' OR isAdmin = 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
DELETE FROM t
WHERE NOT (a AND b)
```

The negation of `a AND b` is `NOT a OR NOT b`

so your query should be

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE NOT (FirstName = 'Ben' AND isAdmin = 1);
```

or

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE FirstName <> 'Ben' OR isAdmin <> 1);
```

Personally I think the first option identifies the intent more clearly. There should not be any performance difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all of the rows **except** where those conditions are true, you would likely want to use the [`NOT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189455.aspx) operator, which may read a bit better than reversing the logic with an `OR` statement :

```
DELETE 
  FROM Table1
 WHERE NOT (FirstName = 'Ben' AND isAdmin = 1);
```

You can [see an interactive example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fbccc/3) which demonstrates the table contents before the query :

[image]

and after the query :

[image]